# $\Delta$- formula for coprime and zeros of polynomial

Tags: logic

I'm trying to figure out how to write bounded-quantifying formulas for $Coprime(x,y)$ and $\{a \in \mathbb{N}|\gamma(a)=0\} $ where roots of $\gamma(x) = w_ix^{w_i} + w_{i-1}x^{w_{i-1}} + ... + w_1 x + w_0 = 0$ where coefficients are all in $\mathbb{N}$.

For the first case, as we know, two numbers $x$ and $y$ are coprimes if $gcb(x,y)=1$. So:

$Coprime(x,y) = (\exists k\le x)(\exists k\le y)((k|x \wedge k|y)\implies k=1)$

For the second case:

$\gamma(a) = (\exists w_i<a)(\exists w_{i-1}<a)...(\exists w_0<a)(w_i.aEw_i + w_{i-1}.aEw_{i-1} + ... + w_0 = 0)$

My questions are:

1- I can write the first case as $Coprime(x,y) = prime(x) \wedge prime(y)$. Is this formula completely equivalent with the former derivation?

What about this one:

$Coprime(x,y) = prime(x) \wedge prime(y) \wedge (\exists k\le x)(\exists k\le y)((k|x \wedge k|y)\implies k=1)$

2- If I relax the assumption of coefficients $\in \mathbb{N}$, then considered bounded quantifiers won't be valid anymore. I think there is no $\Delta$-formula for this case. Am I right?

Thanks

Comment: Your first answer for coprime doesn't work, as if it did, any two numbers would be coprime. Your second one doesn't work either because $x,y$ can be coprime without any of them being prime. Moreover you must check that $k|x$ is a $\Delta$-formula

Comment: As for the second part, it doesn't really make sense, because if the coefficient are non negative integers, and if $w_0 \neq 0$ there can be no non negative integer roots

Comment: @Max Could you please fix the aforesaid issues, then, as TT these answers were my best shots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second one I think you need to change the question (otherwise either $w_0 =0$, and then $\gamma(x)=0 \iff x=0 $ (assuming $i\geq 1$), either $w_0 >0$ and then $\gamma(x) =0 \iff x\neq x$).

For the first question though, being coprime meana that *for every* integer $k$ smaller than the two, that divides them, $k$ is $1$.

So first we need to write down $k|x$ in a $\Delta$ fashion. $k|x$ means that there exists $p$ such that $pk = x$. But this $p$ has to be $\leq x$, and so we have the following : $k|x \iff (\exists p\leq x), p*k = x$.

Now we don't have to worry about it and we can write out what I said earlier : 
$coprime(x,y) \iff (\forall k\leq x), (k\leq y \implies (k|x \land k|y \implies k=1))$

This reads : "For any $k$ that is smaller than both $x,y$, if $k$ divides them both, then $k$ must be $1$.", which is the definition of coprimality.

If you have further questions, let me know